# Adding A navigation drawer bar to the following code?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm fairly new here so I was wondering can someone advise me on a way to implement a navigation drawer activity in the main activity? The code is downloadable from the following links with the source code being the second link and the first link the explanation of how it is done (This isn't my code just to point out):

http://blog.grafixartist.com/image-gallery-app-android-studio-1-4-glide/
https://github.com/Suleiman19/Gallery

It would be very much appreciated and thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can directly implement navigation drawer in your main activity if you are using android studio.
right click on your java folder and go to new->activity->navigation drawer activity.
everything is setup for you (action bar toggle button , lists , icons , onclick methods etc.)

you can edit the list items in menu folder take activity_main_drawer.xml file.

Comment: Thank you. But that is not the solution as it comes up with an error when when I try to implement the NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener which is part of that activity

Comment: what is the error? is it when you run the app it crashes or it is an error in syntax.